# Set default time in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

How to set default time as 00:00 in new row without affecting existing row. I am using the following code for datetimepicker.

```
$('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker({ 
               format : "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",               
                     pickSeconds:false,    
                    }).on("show",function(e) { 
                if($("#fromdate"+ rowIndx).val() == ""){ 
                $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker("setDate", "");                 
                }                 
               });
```

No need to affect already existing row. Need to set time 00:00 in new row only. where can I give the setTime condition?

Answer (score -1):

Add defaultTime: '00:00' and Try:

```
$('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker({ 
               format : "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",               
                     pickSeconds:false,
                     defaultTime: '00:00'    
                    }).on("show",function(e) { 
                if($("#fromdate"+ rowIndx).val() == ""){ 
                $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker("setDate", "");                 
                }                 
               });
```